# How do i track button presses

Tags: powershell

Im a building a powwershell form that triggers relays to turn on and off and wanted to keep track of which buttons are used and many times each one has been pressed.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that? Where are you stuck? If you want qualified help, show us your existing code and what you've tried and how it failed :)

Comment: i am new to using powershell so i dont now how to go about starting a counter. i have 4 buttons that need to be tracked.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't read minds, nor can we see the screen on your end. Please provide the code in which you need assistance with.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach event action blocks to the buttons' `Click` events, increment your counters there:

```
# Create a hashtable to store the button counters at the start of the script
$buttonClickCounters = @{}

# define form components here etc...

# Assuming $button1 contains a System.Windows.Forms.Button:
$button1.add_Click({
  # someone clicked the button, increment counter
  $buttonClickCounters['button1']++

  # implement whatever the button is actually supposed to affect down here
})
```

Once the form has run, you can inspect the individual number of button clicks by inspecting the values stored in the hashtable:

```
$buttonClickCounters['button1'] -as [int] # this expression will now resolve to the number of times the first button was clicked
```